# Rails routing error with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

Firstly, I am new to Rails so please excuse me if this is a lame newbie question

I am creating specials (which `belongs_to :shop`) with a rails `form_tag`

In my admin/specials/new.html.erb, the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag new_admin_shop_special_path(@current_shop) do |f| %>
  <input type = "number" name = "product_ids" />

<% end %>
```

(The path `new_admin_shop_special_path` definitely **does** exist)
In rake routes I have:

```
                       POST   /admin/shops/:shop_id/specials(.:format)                            admin/specials#create
new_admin_shop_special GET    /admin/shops/:shop_id/specials/new(.:format)                           admin/specials#new
```

My admin/specials_controller.rb has:

```
  def new
  end

  def create
    special = @current_shop.specials.build
    special.add_products(params[:product_ids])
    redirect_to admin_shop_shipping_options_path, notice: "#{special.id}"
  end
```

(The notice is for debugging)

So, problem is, if I submit the form, I get an error saying

> ## Routing Error
>
> No route matches [POST] "/admin/shops/dear-rae/specials/new"

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming you use resources:

```
<%= form_tag admin_shop_specials_path(@current_shop) do |f| %>
```

And yes, the path with `new` on the end does exist, but only with `GET` method. When you submit your form, `POST` method is used, which is not applicable for this route.